# KafkaConsumer poll() behavior understanding

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

Trying to understand (new to kafka)how the poll event loop in kafka works.

Use Case : 25 records on the topic, max poll size is set to 5.

`max.poll.interval.ms = 5000   //5 seconds by default max.poll.records = 5`

Sequence of tasks

1. Poll the records from the topic.
2. Process the records in a for loop.
3. Some processing login where the logic would either pass or fail.
4. If logic passes (with offset) will be added to a map.
5. Then it will be committed using commitSync call.
6. **If fails then the loop will break and whatever was success before this would be committed.The problem starts after this.**
7. **The next poll would just keep moving in batches of 5 even after error, is it expected?**

What we basically expect is that the loop breaks and the offsets till success process message logic should get committed, then the next poll should continue from the failed message.

Example, 1st batch of poll 5 messages polled and 1,2 offsets successful and committed then 3rd failed.So the poll call keep moving to next batch like 5-10,10-15 if there are any errors in between we expect it to stop at that point and poll should start from 3 in first case or if it fails in 2nd batch at 8 then the next poll should start from 8th offset not from next max poll batch settings which would be like 5 in this case.IF IT MATTERS USING SPRING BOOT PROJECT and enable autocommit is false.

I have tried finding this in documentation but no help.

tried tweaking this but no help `max.poll.interval.ms`

**EDIT: Not accepted answer because there is no direct solution for a customer consumer.Keeping this for informational purpose**

Answer (score 1):

`max.poll.interval.ms` is milliseconds, not seconds so it should be 5000.

Once the records have been returned by the poll (and offsets not committed), they won't be returned again unless you restart the consumer or perform `seek()` operations on the consumer to reset the offset to the unprocessed ones.

The Spring for Apache Kafka project provides a `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` to perform this task for you.

If you are using the consumer yourself (which it sounds like), you must do the seeks.

Comment: sorry my bad, i meant 5000 milliseconds. You are right we are using consumer ourselves and doing the poll,process and commit .I did try the option to seek() but that looks like a hack to me. When we restart the polling starts from last committed offset, should not the same happen when there is a error and the poll should point to the last committed offset to start of in next max poll batch. And also it's kind of hard to find references to this behavior to make it sound like a actual fix and not a hack :)

Comment: also is this behavior  different in Apache Kafka vs Confluent Kafka? calling seek before every poll would require a new variable to save the current successfull committed offset and seek on every poll cycle , would not that be a performance hit?

Comment: >`should not the same happen when there is a error ` No, it should not. The poll() doesn't know anything about any errors you had processing the records - all it knows is the positions of the last batch of records sent to the consumer; hence, if you want to rewind, you have to perform seeks. There is no requirement to commit the offsets for a poll before the next poll. You don't need to seek on every poll, only when you have an error and need to replay that record (and any remaining in the same batch). The behavior is the same with Confluent.

Comment: How to use this .setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler()) when we are not using ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory or KafkaMessageListenerContainer, we are using KafkaConsumer it does not have any set error handler.

Comment: You can't - since you are not using spring-kafka and are using the `KafkaConsumer` yourself, you will have to implement similar logic yourself. I just pointed you there for an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually seek to the beginning offset of the poll for all the assigned partitions on failure. I am not sure using spring consumer.

Sample code for seeking offset to beginning for normal consumer.
In the code below I am getting the records list per partition and then getting the offset of the first record to seek to.

```
def seekBack(records: ConsumerRecords[String, String]) = {
    records.partitions().map(partition => {
      val partitionedRecords = records.records(partition)
      val offset = partitionedRecords.get(0).offset()
      consumer.seek(partition, offset)
    })
  }
```

One problem doing this in production is bad since you don't want seekback all the time only in cases where you have a transient error otherwise you will end up retrying infinitely.